# What are the differences between Windows Bash and Cygwin?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

What are the differences between Windows Bash and Cygwin?

The new update from Windows with "Linux" Bash is new, but what differences are there to Cygwin that might make you choose one over the other?

Comment: I suppose the windows bash is better integrated and better supported by Microsoft.

Comment: I think this question is on topic as Windows Bash is a Canonical supported product. It may be off topic as perhaps opinion rather then support.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Cygwin is a great tool if you want to live entirely in Windows and want to drive/automate Windows tasks with bash scripts. However, Cygwin is unable to run unmodified Linux binaries.

That's where WSL steps in:

The Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), is a new layer of the Windows kernel which aims to provide a high degree of compatibility with the Linux kernel ABI. This allows native, unmodified, Linux ELF64 binaries to run on WSL.

This is how WSL can run a genuine Ubuntu user-land distro, and any packages you download from apt-get, or .deb packages from elsewhere, without any changes.

The point of WSL is to enable developers working on Windows to be able to run many of the tools, and to work on many projects, which depend on Linux binaries, features, behaviors, filesystem layout, process model, etc.

While WSL is still early in its implementation, we're working hard to improve the breadth and depth of our syscall implementations to steadily improve WSL's ability to run an ever larger set of tools, and support a rapidly growing number of Ruby, Java, node, etc. packages and projects.

---

### Update: 2017-09-07

Since writing the above, we've shipped Windows 10 Creators Update which MASSIVELY improves WSL's compatibility with MANY of the tools you'll want/need to run.

Development has also continued unabated and we've been shipping Win10 Insiders builds over the last few months on the way to the Fall Creators Update (FCU) shipping in Oct 2017.

In FCU, we're adding the ability to install and run more than one distro side-by-side: Ubuntu, openSUSE, and SLES are currently available, with Fedora and others on the way. WSL also now supports USB-serial comms, and mounting of USB-storage and network shares, along with further improvements to our syscalls which improves compatibility with more tools.

---

### Update: 2019-08-22

It's been a very busy couple of years since first announcing and releasing WSL, then adding support for multiple distros via the store, and announcing WSL v1.0
HTH.

At Build 2019 we announced [the new Windows Terminal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/introducing-windows-terminal/) ([Terminal session video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMudkRcwjCw&t=222s)) and [WSL 2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/announcing-wsl-2/) ([WSL 2 session video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lwhMThePdIo&t=5s)) which introduces a whole new approach to running Linux on Windows.

For more details and future updates, be sure to visit the Windows Command-Line blog every couple of weeks where we post lots of related news

Comment: I've been a cygwin user for years. WSL is a fantastic idea that mostly runs well... however at this stage it's file access speed is dog slow. I'll say prohibitively slow. Doing even medium sized operations with something like GIT take in the order of 30+ seconds versus sub second on Cygwin. Hopefully they'll get to fixing that.

Comment: Disk perf is a known issue: We're working on some perf improvements for Win10 CU, with more substantial improvements coming later in 2017.

Comment: Fantastic. Can't wait. It's going to be a great product :-)

Comment: I am still waiting for usb devices support, that is the one thing that is a big miss for me.

Comment: @DamienSawyer it's been over 6 months. Have your speed complaints been lessened or are they still the same?

Comment: @RichTurner You write as if you are an MS insider? If so can you comment on my answer below about what version of Windows is required to install  WSL?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix - I haven't noticed / heard of any improvements. Mind you, I haven't really been using it, instead just sticking with Cygwin (and Docker containers running bash). I figure that, if / when it improves there'll be an announcement in the tech press and I'll give it another shot then.

Comment: If I ever get Windows 10 64-bit I'll do some performance studies and try to remember to post back an answer on this thread.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix - I am the PM for WSL & Windows Console. Follow me at https://twitter.com/richturn_ms

Comment: WSL's disk perf isn't yet where we want it. We're working on improving things in future releases. For a perf comparison vs. native Linux on same tin, see Phoronix's awesome testing: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu-wsl-opensuse&num=1

Comment: @MartijnvanWezel - Take a look at our recent insiders builds: We now support USB-serial comms :)

Comment: @RichTurner Unfortunately I gave up twitter 3 or 4 years ago and facebook 6 or 7 years ago. But I'm happy to see you around here keeping the Ubuntu community informed. Most developers shy away from public forums.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Sad to hear: While Twitter can be a bit ... ahem ... distracting sometimes, following those that you're interested in and respect will at least help keep you up to date with stuff that often moves so fast it's tough to document! ;) Also keep an eye on our blog at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline where I tend to announce significant features and share cool WSL/Console related info.

Comment: @RichTurner Thanks for your blog link. I added it to my `bash` bookmark bar. Twitter distractions should be ignored but unfortunately I'm the kind that chance down incorrect facts and try to point out the truth. Such a futile effort in that wild west environment. Twas best to escape the battle fields.

Comment: @RichTurner then I will run the update :D

Comment: I've spent the last 24 hours binge watching Channel 9 and other msdn sponsored videos. I've ordered a new Win 10 laptop and am keen on installing WSL along with 3rd party x-windows apps to port over all my 1 year of bash work. Q: October is here and I can't find a release date for Fall Creators update?

Comment: As per our blog post from last week (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/10/11/whats-new-in-wsl-in-windows-10-fall-creators-update/), FCU starts shipping tomorrow!

Comment: Do you have updates for your answer, now almost 2 year later? (BTW, +1 for your original answer).

Comment: @RichardErickson - Have added an update above - please be sure to follow our blog, and/or follow me on Twitter for all the latest Terminal / WSL news as it happens ;)

Comment: When are you going to implement usb support @RichTurner?

Comment: @RichTurner Thank you for the update. I PM'd you on twitter with a specific comment.

Comment: @MartijnvanWezel - we added USB serial & USB storage support back in 1703. The team are working on great USB support in WSL2.

Comment: Nice that you added, but I don speak for myself alone that it is currently not working as we would expect.

Comment: I am sure the team would appreciate a more detailed bug report in their repo: https://github.com/microsoft/wsl

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix If you have the time and you're on Windows 10, I would really appreciate those benchmarks right now, trying to determine whether current WSL2 is still slower than Cygwin for I/O.

Comment: @Hashim I heard WSL2 wasn't going to be released until May 2020?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix My bad, you're mostly right, it's currently projected to be released in April. I was confusing the release into the Insiders Program with an official release. Makes sense to wait until the actual release in a month or so's time (!) to benchmark it.

Comment: @Hashim In any respect WSL2 running real Linux Kernel in a VM will be a lot faster than WSL 1. It will be interesting to see if MS has dynamic CPU allocation (for example on my 8 CPU system balance 1 to 7 CPU's to Windows or Linux which has most need) and RAM allocation (for example my 8 GB  system balance RAM between most needed and have other system utilize more SWAP).

Comment: It's most definitely faster than WSL, but it's the speed compared to Cygwin that I'm interested in. I've been using Cygwin for years and I'm trying to decide whether it's a good idea for me to replace it with WSL2.

Comment: @hashim WSL and Cygwin are two different tools. WSL allows you to run genuine unmodified ELF64 Linux binaries on Windows. Using WSL, you can run an entire Linux distro and anything you can install on said distro via apt/zypper/etc. Cygwin is a collection of the GNU tools that have been recompiled to run on Windows. Cygwin cannot run ELF64 Linux binaries directly - it does, however, run Windows apps and tools because Cygwin binaries ARE Windows executables. Further, you can run either where they're most appropriate for your needs.

Comment: @RichTurner I'm unsure why you felt the need to explain all of that to me when I already mentioned above I've been running Cygwin heavily for 5+ years. The real question at this point is whether WSL2 is mature enough to significantly improve on WSL and have its I/O speeds finally comparable to Cygwin's.

Comment: @Hashim. I explained the above because even experienced Cygwin users often ask "what's the point of WSL, I can already run grep in Cygwin" (or similar). Glad you have comprehensive experience of both. WSL2 disk IO perf  approaches that of native Linux when accessing files within the distros' filesystem which is a EXT4 formatted VHDX. There is a perf impact when accessing files stored within Windows' filesystem due to having to traverse the 9P protocol server.

Answer (score 19):

## Windows Subsystem for Linux

I've been using WSL under Windows 10 for about a few months. Finally I can boot into Windows for gaming and still access the bash prompt and run CLI and many GUI programs. There are limitations such as none of the familiar Linux kernel virtual directories. Planning is required to share the same Bash script between Ubuntu and WSL on a dual boot machine.

There are lots of things I'd like to see improved, but I can live with it as is for a year or so.

### Closed source

One thing to remember is Microsoft is a closed system, and you don't get the flurry of third parties writing updates like you enjoy on Linux. But all things considered you buy a new laptop and it comes with Windows 10 anyway so you could say it's "free" at least :)

Cygwin is controlled by Red Hat Linux which is not exactly known for giving things away for free either. Their "free" Linux distribution [Fedora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29) seems like a ["testing ground"](http://www.tuxmachines.org/node/106669) to some.

### Maintenance cycles

Cygwin has 15 years of updates. Notable is the same project manager has been in place since 2003. There are lots of full time maintainers and many more volunteer contributors.

WSL provides major updates twice a year every spring and fall. Weekly minor updates are available to those on the Developers subscription list. Although Microsoft has resources to throw thousands of people into WSL development it appears you can count the [team members](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/10/12/wsl-console-team-changes/) with your fingers.

### Speed issues

You'll see many complaints about WSL speed. For example, screen painting takes many times longer in Windows 10 versus Ubuntu 16.04, i.e. you can actually see the cursor move in Windows 10:

[image: WSL bash startup.gif]

It takes about 5 seconds for the WSL Bash splash screen to paint. By comparison it is about 1 1/2 seconds for the same splash screen in Ubuntu 16.04:

[image: Ubuntu terminal splash.gif]

Cygwin has its own share of [speed complaints with Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512892/how-to-speed-up-cygwin?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

---

### Original posting below for historical reference.

With Windows 10 Home, **if** it's 32 bit Windows, it means it won't run the 64-bit Ubuntu / Windows Subsystem as Microsoft tells us here: ([windows Linux subsystem in win10 HOME BASIC](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/can-we-get-windows-linux-subsystem-in-win10-home/ba93f9ac-25de-4dc6-9652-c63b3a26e0a8?auth=1)).

It's like a dream come true running Ubuntu on Windows with its superior gaming support for Nvidia, but before you run out and buy a new (or used) laptop, make sure it has Windows 10 64 bit and not the 32-bit home version if you want to run Ubuntu / Linux stuff natively under Windows. On Microsoft websites they actually refer to the Windows Anniversary edition as a prerequisite to running Windows Subsystem for Linux.

---

However if you don't want to shell out $200+ for Windows 10 and you have an older laptop running Windows 8.1 64-bit like I do, and you have an even older laptop running Windows Vista 64 bit like I do, then Cygwin is the answer.

Cygwin supports more versions of Windows [as their website lists](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.what.supported):

> Cygwin can be expected to run on all modern, released versions of
> Windows. State January 2016 this includes Windows Vista, Windows
> Server 2008 and all later versions of Windows up to Windows 10 and
> Windows Server 2016. The 32 bit version of Cygwin also runs in the
> WOW64 32 bit environment on released 64 bit versions of Windows, the
> 64 bit version of course only on 64 bit Windows.
>
> Keep in mind that Cygwin can only do as much as the underlying OS
> supports. Because of this, Cygwin will behave differently, and exhibit
> different limitations, on the various versions of Windows.

Comment: The question is what the differences between cygwin and bash for windows are. Cygwin isn't even mentioned in your answer. Please clarify how this answers the question.

Comment: @Seth I pointed out how WSL is version specific whereas Cygwin runs on all supported versions of WIndows. Thanks for pointing out my oversight.

Comment: We've been very clear that WSL requires 64-bit Windows, and is available in every Windows 10 SKU, except current LTSB - WSL will be added to the next LTSB release. WSL is also going to be included in Windows Server released in fall 2017.

Comment: @RichTurner Your website clearly spells it out. What's not clear to me (and not your fault) is why the vendor sells an i7 quad core 7700 with Nvidia 1050 GPU and 12 GB of system RAM with Windows 10 home. Someone deleted the original link [but here it is](https://www.staples.ca/en/MSI-GP72-7RDX-452CA-17-3-Gaming-Laptop-2-8-GHz-Intel-Core-i7-7700HQ-1-TB-HDD-12-GB-DDR4-NVIDIA-GeForce-GTX-1050-Win10-Home/product_2720793_2-CA_1_20001). They do not spell out it's 32-bit. Are you saying every WIndows 10 is 64-bit?

Comment: It's sold as a gaming PC. Since most gamers don't need the additional featuers in Win10 Pro, the opted for Home to save the customer from paying for something they'll likely not need. Windows 10 does come in 32-bit variants too for those that want it, but I'd be ASTONISHED if someone sold a machine with > 4GB RAM and installed a 32-bit OS since the OS and apps that it runs would not be able to access anything > 4GB.

Comment: @RichTurner I saw the same laptop on newegg site and there it states Windows Home 64-bit. I assume the people setting up Staple's website just omitted the 64-bit part to save space or not confuse their stereo-typical consumer. Either way I've enhanced my search for a more powerful GPU ~ GTX 1070.